# How To Span Columns Pandas with Multiple Column Cells

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, group-by

:)

I have the following DataFrame

| Fruit Type | Fruit1 | Fruit2 | Fruit3 | Fruit4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Berries |  |  |  |  |
|  | Raspberry | Blueberry | Passionfruit | Kiwi |
|  | Raspberry | Blueberry | Passionfruit | Kiwi |
| Citrus |  |  |  |  |
|  | Grapefruit | Mandarins | Lemon | Lime |
|  | Grapefruit | Mandarins | Lemon | Lime |
| Melons |  |  |  |  |
|  | Rockmelon | Honeydew | Muskmelon | Zucchini |
|  | Rockmelon | Honeydew | Muskmelon | Zucchini |

I'm trying to get the Fruit Types to span across all the other columns like titles across their fruit families. So just 1 cell spanning multiple columns, like when you drag multiple cells horizontally in excel and click merge cells.

I don't know how to show the output in Stack but I want it to look like 'Berries' is one cell which spans columns Fruit 1, Fruit2, Fruit3 and Fruit 4 and the same for Citrus and Melons and then I can remove the Fruit Type Column entirely.

Comment: You can't **span** multiple columns in pandas. You can duplicate the value if you want

Comment: Is there a way to then duplicate berries until citrus vertically and then duplicate citrus until melons and then do the same for melons?

Comment: Yes: `df['Fruit Type'] = df['Fruit Type'].mask(df['Fruit Type'].eq('')).ffill()` Or if you already have NaNs in the empty cells: `df['Fruit Type'] = df['Fruit Type'].ffill()`

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks :)